# A question regarding an analog of Young symmetrizer: the product row and column preserving subgroups without sign representation

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

Consider a rectangular Young diagram $\lambda$ with $n = pq$ boxes, with $p$ rows and $q$ columns. If $C$ is the column preserving subgroup of $\lambda$ and $R$ is the row preserving subgroup, then we normaly construct the Young symmetrizer by defining
$$b = \sum_{g \in C} \text{sign}(g) g,$$ and, $$a = \sum_{g \in R} g,$$ and the Young symmetrizer is $$c = ba.$$

I am studying a slightly different problem, where one defines $b$ without $\text{sign}(g)$:
$$b' = \sum_{g \in C} g,$$ and then the analog of the Young symmetrizer is $c' =b' a$, the product of row and column preserving subgroups.

It is easy to see that unlike $c$, $c'$ is not an idempotent, i.e., $c' c' \neq \alpha c'$ for any $\alpha$. Nevertheless, I would like to compute $\frac{1}{n!}\text{tr} (c' c')$ in the regular representation, i.e. the number of $(r_1,c_1,r_2,c_2)$ with $r_1,r_2 \in R$ and $c_1,c_2 \in C$ where $r_1 c_1 r_2 c_2 = id$.

Indeed, one simple lower bound for  $\frac{1}{n!}\text{tr} (c' c')$ is  $\frac{1}{n!}\text{tr} (c c) = \text{hook length}(\lambda) \times \frac{1}{n!}\text{tr}(c) =\text{hook length}(\lambda).$

Is there anything known in the literature about the unsigned row and column product $c'$? or the particular trace that I wish to compute?